# How do I make an individual Rocket tile asynchronous to the rest of the system

Tags: chisel, rocket-chip

I have a multicore rocket-chip system. However I'd like one of those rocket tiles to be asynchronous from the rest.

We're trying to do that with the following:

```
class WithTilesCrossing extends Config((site, here, up) => {
  case RocketCrossingKey => site(RocketTilesKey).head.hartId match {
    case 2 => up(RocketCrossingKey) map { r =>
      r.copy(crossingType = AsynchronousCrossing(),
             master = TileMasterPortParams())}
    case _ => up(RocketCrossingKey) map { r =>
      r.copy(crossingType = SynchronousCrossing(BufferParams(1)),
             master = TileMasterPortParams())}
  }
})
```

So that is the hart with `hartId = 2` should be async, the rest should be synchronous.

The above, when added to our config, doesn't appear to do anything.

However, if I use the `WithAsynchronousRocketTiles` from `src/main/scala/subsystem/Config.scala` then I get all of the tiles converted to async.

So, how would I do just a single tile?

Update based on Jack's suggestion:

Trying that code straight up gave:

```
[error] Config.scala:189:16: not found: value crossingType
[error]         r.copy(crossingType = AsynchronousCrossing(),
[error]                ^
[error] Config.scala:190:11: not found: value master
[error]           master = TileMasterPortParams())
[error]           ^
[error] Config.scala:192:16: not found: value crossingType
[error]         r.copy(crossingType = SynchronousCrossing(BufferParams(1)),
[error]                ^
[error] Config.scala:193:11: not found: value master
[error]           master = TileMasterPortParams())
[error]           ^
[error] four errors found
```

Which is surprising. So I thought I might need to do the `up()` thing and tried this:

```
  case RocketCrossingKey => site(RocketTilesKey).map { r =>
    r.hartId match {
      case 2 => up(RocketCrossingKey) map { k => k.copy(crossingType = AsynchronousCrossing(), master = TileMasterPortParams()) }
      case _ => up(RocketCrossingKey) map { k => k.copy(crossingType = SynchronousCrossing(BufferParams(1)), master = TileMasterPortParams()) }
    }
  }
```

However that results in an elab error:

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon cannot be cast to freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.RocketCrossingParams
[error]         at freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.HasRocketTiles.$anonfun$rocketTiles$1(RocketSubsystem.scala:41)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]         at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
[error]         at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:295)
[error]         at freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.HasRocketTiles.$init$(RocketSubsystem.scala:41)
[error]         at freechips.rocketchip.subsystem.RocketSubsystem.<init>(RocketSubsystem.scala:70)
```

So still stuck on how to modify this original `RocketCrossingParams` on a per-tile basis and return it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [definition of `RocketCrossingKey`:](https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/4c6977a766f96de28e023c6c6837b35259b4aa87/src/main/scala/subsystem/RocketSubsystem.scala#L26)

```scala
case object RocketCrossingKey extends Field[Seq[RocketCrossingParams]](List(RocketCrossingParams()))
```

You'll notice that the type is `Seq[RocketCrossingParams]`. This implies (although I may be wrong), that we have 1 `RocketCrossingParams` per tile. In your code snippet, you are only looking at the first of the this `Seq` (via `.head`) checking if it's `hartId` is equal to 2, and then if so, iterating on all of the `RocketCrossingKey`s and setting them to `AsynchronousCrossing`.

Try something like the following where we iterate on them and only replace the index for the one with `hartId == 2`:

```scala
case RocketCrossingKey => site(RocketTilesKey).map { r =>
  if (r.hartId == 2) { // or you can match on it, whatever
    r.copy(crossingType = AsynchronousCrossing(),
           master = TileMasterPortParams())
  } else {
    r.copy(crossingType = SynchronousCrossing(BufferParams(1)),
           master = TileMasterPortParams())
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I missed the fact that there is both `RocketCrossingKey` and `RocketTilesKey`

So the issue here is that there are two parallel `Seq`s of parameters:

- `RocketTilesKey` which gives us `RocketTileParams`, 1 for each tile
- `RocketCrossingKey` which gives us `RocketCrossingParams`, 1 for each tile **OR** if there's only 1, it applies to all

It's also possible that there is no `RocketTileParams` containing `hartId == 2`, so let's handle everything appropriately:

```scala
  case RocketCrossingKey =>
    val tileParams = site(RocketTilesKey)
    val crossingParams = site(RocketCrossingKey)

    // One might assume hartId 2 == index 2 but that may not be the case
    // Also there may not even *be* a tile with hartId == 2
    val indexOfHartId2: Option[Int] =
      tileParams.zipWithIndex.collectFirst { case (r, idx) if r.hartId == 2 => idx }

    indexOfHartId2.map { idx =>
      // This duplicates logic from HasTiles.perTileOrGlobalSetting
      // If there's only 1, it applies to all
      val crossings = site(RocketCrossingKey) match {
        case Seq(one) => List.fill(tileParams.size)(one)
        case many     => many
      }
      // Back to the original answer using the proper index for hartId == 2
      crossings.zipWithIndex.map { case (c, i) =>
        if (i == idx) { // or you can match on it, whatever
          c.copy(crossingType = AsynchronousCrossing(),
                 master = TileMasterPortParams())
        } else {
          c.copy(crossingType = SynchronousCrossing(BufferParams(1)),
                 master = TileMasterPortParams())
        }
      }
    }.getOrElse(crossingParams) // If we don't even have hardId == 2, return original value
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, thanks very much!

However, my Scala/Chisel skills are not able to massage your suggestion into something which works.

Trying your code as-is says it can't find `crossingType` or `master`?? (Sorry the following is mangled by stackoverflow's awful formatting rules in these comments :-/)


`[error] Config.scala:189:16: not found: value crossingType
[error]         r.copy(crossingType = AsynchronousCrossing(),
[error]                ^
[error] Config.scala:190:11: not found: value master
[error]           master = TileMasterPortParams())
[error]           ^`